# Optimisation: $H(X_1) + H(X_2) +H(X_3) - H(X_1+X_2+X_3)$

Tags: pr.probability

> Consider the following optimisation.
> $$\max [H(X_1) + H(X_2) +H(X_3) - H(X_1+X_2+X_3)],$$
> where H denotes the Shannon entropy, `+` denotes addition over real numbers, and the maximum is taken over all the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ that are independent Bernoulli.
>
> **Question**: How to prove that the maximum is achieved when $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ follow a uniform distribution?

**Edit** (as requested): For a discrete random variable $X$ with probability mass function $p$ with support $\mathcal{X}$, $H(X) = - \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x) \log p(x)$.

Comment: Equivalent formulation: maximize the conditional entropy of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ given $X_1+X_2+X_3$, where $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ are independent Bernoulli random variables (with possibly different parameters).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you, you are perfectly right. It can also be written as $H(X_1) + H(X_2) + H(X_3) - H(X_1+X_2+X_3)$. Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, only little is known about the entropy of the sum of random variables.

Comment: @user64494  Yes, I definitely want an analytical solution as written in the post

Comment: Would you care to provide a (link to) an explict formula for $H(Y)$, for $H$ as in the latest displayed formula in the question?

Comment: Is $H(Y)$ concave?

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik Yes, H is concave, I have also added the definition

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: This is a nice idea, but conditional entropy is a concave function of the *measure*. To be specific: let $\mu$ be the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ on $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1\}^3$, let $\mathcal{E}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the field generated by $X_1+X_2+X_3$. Then $H_\mu(\mathcal{E}|\mathcal{F})$ is a concave function of $\mu$. But it does *not* imply that $H_\mu(\mathcal{E}|\mathcal{F})$ is a concave function of $x,y,z$: $\mu$ does not depend on $(x,y,z)$ in a linear way.

Comment: That said, $\mu$ is a linear function of each of the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ separately. Therefore, $H_\mu(\mathcal{E}|\mathcal{F})$ is a concave function of $x$, $y$ and $z$ separately. Had this function been also *symmetric* with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$, a symmetrisation argument would have implied that the maximum necessarily corresponds to $x = \tfrac{1}{2}$, and similarly $y = z = \tfrac{1}{2}$. Is there a way around to avoid a symmetry argument?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki - a function on the space of measures (a functional, that is)? 

Further, do I understand it right that $\mathcal{X}$ is just 2 points, and the formula for $H(Y)$ is something like $H(Y)=-y\log y -(1-y)\log(1-y)$ ? (where $y$ is the parameter of the corresponding Bernoulli distribution)?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Yes, a (non-linear) functional on the space of measures. However, $\mathcal{X}$ consists of 8 points, all possible outcomes of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$: $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, etc. Also, I do not know why I wrote that $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are fields rather then partitions: $\mathcal{E}$ should be the collection of all singletons, and $\mathcal{F}$ consists of $\{(0,0,0)\}$, $\{(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$, $\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,1,1)\}$.

Comment: To complete the picture: $$H_\mu(\mathcal{E}|\mathcal{F}) = -\sum_{A \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{B \in \mathcal{E}} \mu(A \cap B) \log \frac{\mu(A \cap B)}{\mu(A)} \, .$$ For the concavity of $H_\mu(\mathcal{E}|\mathcal{F})$ with respect to $\mu$, see, for example, [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080334/428180).

Comment: ok, now it starts to make sense to a non-probabilist... there is also no $\cal{E,F}$ in the question....

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partly analytic solution done in Maple 2017.3.
First, the result of

```
f := -(1-x)*(1-y)*z*ln((1-x)*(1-y)*z/((1-x)*(1-y)*z+(1-x)*y*(1-z)+x*(1-y)*(1-z)))-
(1-x)*y*(1-z)*ln((1-x)*y*(1-z)/((1-x)*(1-y)*z+(1-x)*y*(1-z)+x*(1-y)*(1-z)))-
x*(1-y)*(1-z)*ln(x*(1-y)*(1-z)/((1-x)*(1-y)*z+(1-x)*y*(1-z)+x*(1-y)*(1-z)))-
(1-x)*y*z*ln((1-x)*y*z/((1-x)*y*z+x*(1-y)*z+x*y*(1-z)))-
x*(1-y)*z*ln(x*(1-y)*z/((1-x)*y*z+x*(1-y)*z+x*y*(1-z)))-
x*y*(1-z)*ln(x*y*(1-z)/((1-x)*y*z+x*(1-y)*z+x*y*(1-z))):
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(f, {x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, x <= 1, y <= 1, z <= 1}, maximize);
```

$$[.823959216501083, [x = .500000007051357, y = .500000002907430, z = .499999998207894], 448]
 $$
means the global maximum of $f$ on the cube $[0,1]^3$ is reached at the point 
$x = .500000007051357, y = .500000002907430, z = .499999998207894$ with the absolute error 
$10^{-6}$ (see the help to  [DirectSearch](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=101333)).
Second, the result of

```
DirectSearch:-SolveEquations([diff(f, x) = 0, diff(f, y) = 0, diff(f, z) = 0],
 {x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, x <= 1, y <= 1, z <= 1}, AllSolutions, solutions = 5);
```

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} { 1.23259516440783095\times 10^{-32}}&
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} -{ 1.11022302462515654\times 10^{-16}}
\\  0.0\\  0.0\end {array}
 \right] &[x= 0.500000000000000000,y= 0.499999999999999944,z=
 0.499999999999999944]&154\end {array} \right] 
$$
means there is  only one critical point of $f$ inside the cube  $[0,1]^3$ and this point is close to
$x=\frac 1 2,y= \frac 1 2,z=\frac 1 2$. It is easy to verify that the 
point $x=\frac 1 2,y= \frac 1 2,z=\frac 1 2$ is a critical point of $f$.
Third, the results of

```
Student[MultivariateCalculus]:- SecondDerivativeTest(f, [x,y,z] = [1/2, 1/2, 1/2],output='hessian');
```

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -8/3&-\ln  \left( 3 \right) +4/3&-\ln 
 \left( 3 \right) +4/3\\ -\ln  \left( 3 \right) +4/3
&-8/3&-\ln  \left( 3 \right) +4/3\\-\ln  \left( 3
 \right) +4/3&-\ln  \left( 3 \right) +4/3&-8/3\end {array} \right] 
$$
and

```
Student[MultivariateCalculus]:- SecondDerivativeTest(f, [x, y, z] = [1/2, 1/2, 1/2]);
```

${\it LocalMin}=[],{\it LocalMax}=[[1/2,1/2,1/2]],{\it Saddle}=[]$

mean that the critical point $x=\frac 1 2,y= \frac 1 2,z=\frac 1 2$ is the maximum point.
Summing up the above, we conclude, that the global maximum is reached at.

Comment: @the downvoter: What is bad in my answer? TIA.

Comment: Can Maple write down the Hessian of f?

Comment: (I was not the downvoter, to the contrary...)

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Yes, Maple does it by VectorCalculus:-Hessian(f, [x, y,z])

Comment: @user64494 Thanks! Unfortunately, it does not provide an analytic proof, that's why I do not validate it as an answer to the post

Comment: @user64494 For an analytic proof, the key point with your method would be to prove that there is only one critical point in $(0,1)^3$

Comment: the question about the Hessian would be to see whether it is negative definite on the domain we maximize.

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Unfortunately, H := VectorCalculus:-Hessian(f, [x, y, z]):
assume(0 < x, x < 1, 0 < y, y < 1, 0 < z, z < 1):
K := LinearAlgebra:-IsDefinite(H, query = 'negative_definite'); performs [Length of output exceeds limit of  1000000].

Comment: it is expected. How about the Hessian itself with simplified entries?

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Huge.

Comment: Is it more manageable if you reduce to radial directions? Let $(u,v,w) = (x,y,z) - (1/2,1/2,1/2)$. The conjecture is that the origin is the unique maximum. It suffices along any radial line the function is negative definite. What if we fix $(u_0, v_0, w_0)$ on $\partial [-1/2,1/2]^3$ and look at the function along the line $r\mapsto r(u_0, v_0, w_0)$? Is this Hessian small enough to show here?

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. Note that $\bar{\bar{x}}=1-\bar{x}=1-(1-x)=x$. Similar for $y$ and $z$. Denote $u:=(x,y,z)$ then $\bar{u}=(\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z})$. So your problem can be rewritten as
$$\max_{u\in(0,1)^3}f(u)+f(\bar{u})$$ 
Note that if $u^*\in\arg\max_{u\in(0,1)^3}f(u)+f(\bar{u})$ then so is $\bar{u}^*$ because 
$$f(\bar{u}^*)+f(\bar{\bar{u}}^*)=f(\bar{u}^*)+f(u^*)=f_{\max}$$
It suffices therefore to prove that $f(u)+f(\bar{u})$ is a strictly concave function of $u\in(0,1)^3$ since in this case if a maximum exists it would be unique. This would force $u^*=\bar{u}^*$ or equivalently $x^*=1-x^*,y^*=1-y^*,z^*=1-z^*$ implying $x^*=y^*=z^*=1/2$.